# Stacking html elements side by side

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, layout

I want to put my 4 HTML elements side by side with a total width of 100%.

```
<input type="number" name="height" placeholder="weight">
<span>kg</span>
<input type="number" name="weight" placeholder="height">
<span>cm</span>
```

But I found lot of answers in stack overflow which are not working. I get something like this...

[image: see the middle w(eight) and h(height)]

Comment: Your question lacks precision. Consider editing it by adding context, code, etc ... See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do you want them to be centered on the page? Do you want the extraneous space to go between elements? Should they stretch to fit?

Answer (score 2):

**Flexbox** allows for easy variations in alignment (in both axis), widths, occupying the remaining width, wrapping or never ever wrapping, etc

You need a parent container, which has `display: flex`. It's the flex container. Now all children are *flex items*.

CSS tricks has a mighty [Cheatsheet for Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Here are 2 examples:

- input occupy the space not occupied by the span (should be label elements isn't it?) - [Codepen](https://codepen.io/PhilippeVay/pen/mqxWKE)
- each element occupies roughly 25% of the width, minus the needed margin between each input and its label - [Codepen](https://codepen.io/PhilippeVay/pen/xPWqyo)

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  background-color: tomato;
}

.container input {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.container span {
  margin: 0 4rem 0 0.5rem;
}

.container span:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="number" name="height" placeholder="weight">
  <span>kg</span>
  <input type="number" name="weight" placeholder="height">
  <span>cm</span>
</div>
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  background-color: beige;
}

.container input,
.container span {
  width: calc(25% - 0.5rem); /* half of the margin set below */
}

.container span {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="number" name="height" placeholder="weight">
  <span>kg</span>
  <input type="number" name="weight" placeholder="height">
  <span>cm</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a good Flexbox answer, but I wonder if it is appropriate given the OP's lack of understanding of basic layout.

Comment: Compared to "inline-block and 4*25%" and oh why the 4th element isn't staying on the 1st line? ;) I don't know how beginners cope with this. On one hand no need to abuse floats for layout (the extreme case from the past), on the other hand Flexbox is powerful with a price: so many properties and values and dozens of possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

`input` and `span` elements are "inline" elements. Their width is only as wide as their content (or, in the case `input`, as wide as you tell them to be). You already have them being laid out side-by-side, but you need to treat them as if they were "block" elements to be able to set `width` so that, in total, they can take up 100% of the available width of the page.

You need to look into **[block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)** vs. **[inline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements)** elements and the **[CSS Box Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model)** to begin to understand how layout works by default in a web page.

Here's an example that causes the `input` fields to stretch to fill the empty space:

```css
input {
  display:inline-block;     /* Allow the inline element to be sized as a block element */
  width:calc(50% - 2.5em);  /* Each will be 50% of the width of the parent - roughly 2.5 characters */
}
```

```html
<input type="number" name="height" placeholder="weight">
<span>kg</span>
<input type="number" name="weight" placeholder="height">
<span>cm</span>
```

Or, if you just want the widths as normal, but want all 4 elements to be centered within the available width, you need to tell the parent element how to horizontally align its child elements, you do that with `text-align`:

```css
.center {
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <input type="number" name="height" placeholder="weight">
  <span>kg</span>
  <input type="number" name="weight" placeholder="height">
  <span>cm</span>
</div>
```